# Retrieving information from ffmpeg shell_exec command

Tags: php, audio, video, ffmpeg, shell-exec

i am doing the following

```
$output = shell_exec('/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i intro.mp3 2>&1'); 
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

This outputs

```
ffmpeg version 0.8.5, Copyright (c) 2000-2011 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Aug 20 2012 09:28:43 with clang 3.1 (tags/Apple/clang-318.0.61)
  configuration: --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-avfilter --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libtheora --enable-libfaac --enable-libxvid --enable-libx264 --enable-libvpx --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --disable-indevs --cc=clang
  libavutil    51.  9. 1 / 51.  9. 1
  libavcodec   53.  7. 0 / 53.  7. 0
  libavformat  53.  4. 0 / 53.  4. 0
  libavdevice  53.  1. 1 / 53.  1. 1
  libavfilter   2. 23. 0 /  2. 23. 0
  libswscale    2.  0. 0 /  2.  0. 0
  libpostproc  51.  2. 0 / 51.  2. 0
[mp3 @ 0x7f9481807c00] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5015510
Input #0, mp3, from 'intro.mp3':
  Metadata:
    album           : Frank 
    artist          : Amy Winehouse
    genre           : R&B
    title           : [Intro] Stronger Than Me
    track           : 01
    date            : 2008
  Duration: 00:03:54.71, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 230 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 160 kb/s
At least one output file must be specified
```

i want to get the information to insert into a database album,artist,genre,title etc

But all seperately

i can get them by doing the following

```
$output = shell_exec('/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i intro.mp3 2>&1'); 

$edit = explode('  ', $output);
$edit = implode("@", $edit);
$edit = explode(':', $output);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($edit);
echo "</pre>";
```

then running

```
<?php echo $edit[9]; ?>
```

etc

but this seems like a really bad way and annoying way to get values and sometimes the output is slightly different which messes with the outputs.

Whats the best way to do this or am i stuck doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a better way to retrieve metadata using ffmpeg.

**1.** Create a new `ffmpeg_movie` object e.g

```
$movie = new ffmpeg_movie(String path_to_media, boolean persistent);
```

**2.** Start getting metada like so:

```
$movie->getAuthor();
$movie->getGenre();
$movie->getAlbum();
```

List of what's available at [ffmpeg-php API documentation](http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/doc/api/ffmpeg_movie.php).

**3.** Celebrate good times.